# Default Tags using ECS Service

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Most of our ECS Services are not in the "new" format that allow tags to be set.

We recently added default tags to our aws provider e.g.:

```
  provider "aws" {
  region  = local.workspace["aws_region"]
  profile = local.workspace["aws_profile"]
    default_tags {
      tags = {
        Environment = local.workspace["releaseStage"]
        Owner       = "terraform"
        Project     = "infrastructure"
        Account     = local.workspace["releaseStage"]
      }
    }
    
}
```

However, if we run terraform apply, it barks at ecs service resources as they don't support tagging:

Error: error updating ECS Service (arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxx:service/myservice) tags: error tagging resource (arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxx:service/myservice): InvalidParameterException: Long arn format must be used for tagging operations

If I override the tags in the resource e.g.:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "myservice" {
  name            = "myservice"
  ...
  tags = {
        Environment = ""
        Owner       = ""
        Project     = ""
        Account     = ""
      }
  
}
```

It works, but I never get a clean terraform plan as it always needs to evaluate the merged tags.

Is there a way to exclude tagging of default_tags with certain resources?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use lifecycle block with ignore_changes to tags which will exclude any external changes. I'm not sure whether this would work. But you can try.

Comment: I tried that. It would exclude changes to existing tags but there are no tags set at this point.